# Remove "Just" from "Just 0.631" when printing a float

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I was given a task to return the area of a valid triangle. However whenever is run my code it prints `Just <float>`. i.e `Just 0.631`. Here is my code:

```
triangleArea :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Maybe Float

triangleArea a b c
  | a+b>=c && b+c>=a && a+c>=b = Just (sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)))
  | otherwise = error "Not a triangle!"
  where
    s=(a+b+c)/2
```

Comment: That's intentional; not all arguments will correspond to a triangle, hence the return type of `Maybe Float` instead of `Float`.

Comment: The "otherwise" case should return `Nothing` instead of calling `error`, though.

Comment: , as part of the task, we must return the error "Not a triangle!"  if it isn't valid. That's why i put maybe float there. I'm not sure if I was right in doing so though.

Comment: It is redundant; `error` causes an [exception](https://wiki.haskell.org/Exception), while `Maybe` offers a functional approach to the same dichotomy. `Either` is sometimes used to provide information with the failure case.

Comment: One usually either uses a `Maybe ...` and returns a `Just x` or a `Nothing`; *or*, one returns a value or an error, but not the two combined.

Answer (score 8):

Not all sets of side lengths will correspond to a real triangle. You have two choices:

1. Define a *partial* function that returns a `Float`, and call `error` to signal an invalid set of lengths. This is **not** the recommended approach in Haskell, though.

   ```
   triangleArea :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
   triangleArea a b c | a + b >= c && a + c >= b && a + c >= b = area                           
                      | otherwise = error "Not a triangle!"
     where s = (a + b + c) / 2
           area = sqrt $ s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)
   ```
2. Recommended: use `Maybe Float` as the return type, and return `Nothing` when the arguments don't define a triangle.

   ```
   triangleArea :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Maybe Float
   triangleArea a b c | a + b >= c && a + c >= b && a + c >= b = Just area
                      | otherwise = Nothing
     where s = (a + b + c) / 2
           area = sqrt $ s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)
   ```

   This forces anyone calling `triangleArea` to deal with the possibility of an undefined triangle, rather than simply crashing the program.

(For completeness, there are other options, namely `Either SomeType Float`, but they are generalizations of #2, where you can provide more specific "error" values than just `Nothing`.)

Comment: Thank you, we had to return error "not a triangle" if it didnt correspond to a traingle. What would be the reccomended approach?

Comment: @hanzn98: If your assignment indicates to use `error`, then simply omit `Maybe` and `Just`. It’s generally better to avoid `error` in a larger codebase, because it doesn’t have the benefit of using types to enforce explicit error handling. The typical approach is to use `Maybe` if there’s a single possible error, or `Either` if there are multiple—e.g., `Either String Float` (or `Either ShapeError Float` with some structured data type `data ShapeError = InvalidTriangle`), with `Right area` for success and `Left "not a triangle"` (resp. `Left InvalidTriangle`) for failure.

Answer (score 3):

```hs
triangleArea :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Maybe Float
```

This line declares that `triangleArea` will be a function that takes 3 `Float` numbers, and returns a `Maybe Float`. A `Maybe` of anything is simply a type in Haskell that can have be `Nothing`, indicating the absence of a value, or `Just x` indicating that there is a value and it is `x`.

This is why in your function you have:

```hs
(condition) = Just (sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)))
```

What is important is that the `(condition)` is when there *will* be a value.

The `otherwise` part is a bit stranger – you probably don't want it to throw an `error` at all. Instead, you can indicate that there is no value (area) for the given parameters, by using `Nothing` as a result:

```hs
triangleArea :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Maybe Float
triangleArea a b c
  | a + b >= c && b + c >= a && a + c >= b = Just (sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)))
  | otherwise = Nothing
  where
    s=(a+b+c)/2
```

Alternatively, the function could have been declared as simply returning `Float`, and throwing an error when given invalid parameters. Make sure to read carefully what the tasks asks you to do, whether you can change the signature, and if so, document what the function does (typical requirement in courseworks/introductory assignments).

Comment: Thank you, I understand it a lot better now! :)